# Scala reduce on Case class with keys

Tags: scala, dictionary, reduce

Below is the scenario of 2 case classes that I have -

```
case class Pack(name: String, age: Int, dob: String)

object Pack{
  def getPack(name:String, age: Int, dob:String): Pack = {
    Pack(name,age,dob)
  }
}

case class NewPack(name: String, pack: (List[Pack]))

object NewPack{
  def getNewPackList(data: List[Pack]): List[NewPack] = {
    val newData = for(x <- data )yield(x.name,List(x))
    val newPackData = for(x <- newData)yield(NewPack(x._1,x._2))
    newPackData
  }
}


val someData = List(Pack.getPack("x",12,"day1"), Pack.getPack("y",23,"day2"),Pack.getPack("x",34,"day3") )

val somePackData = NewPack.getNewPackList(someData)
```

the values of someData and somePackData is like this -

```
someData: List[Pack] = List(Pack(x,12,day1), Pack(y,23,day2), Pack(x,34,day3))

somePackData: List[NewPack] = List(NewPack(x,List(Pack(x,12,day1))), NewPack(y,List(Pack(y,23,day2))), NewPack(x,List(Pack(x,34,day3))))
```

Now I want to get the final data in the below mentioned format. Could anyone suggest me the better way of doing that.

```
finalData: List[NewPack] = List(NewPack(x,List(Pack(x,12,day1),Pack(x,34,day3)),NewPack(y,List(Pack(y,23,day2))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is small simplification.

```
case class Pack(name: String, age: Int, dob: String)

case class NewPack(name: String, pack: List[Pack])

object NewPack{
  def getNewPackList(data: List[Pack]): List[NewPack] = 
    data.map{case pack@Pack(name, _, _) => NewPack(name, List(pack))}
}
```

Note that in general you don't need additional factory method for case class. If you would like to present something tricky later, you can always define custom `apply` in your companion object.

Additionally if you were intending to group packs by name you can easily define something like

```
def newPacksGrouped(data: List[Pack]): List[NewPack] =
  data.groupBy(_.name).map{case (name, packs) => NewPack(name, packs)}.toList
```